# Java : Overridden method does not throw 'java.lang.Throwable'

Tags: java, playframework, completion-stage

I am getting following compile time error

```
call(play.mvc.Http.Context) in actions.Headers cannot override call(play.mvc.Http.Context) in play.mvc.Action
[error]   overridden method does not throw java.lang.Exception
[error]        public CompletionStage<Result> call(final Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
```

here is the code :

```
public CompletionStage<Result> call(final Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
           ctx.response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
           ctx.response().setHeader("Allow", "*");
           ctx.response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
           ctx.response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent, token");
           ctx.response().setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent, token");

           return (CompletionStage<Result>) delegate.call(ctx);
       }
```

I am using play `framework 2.6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/java/index.html) of playframework 2.6 the method call in class Action doesn't throw Thowable anymore, so your method mustn't do that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove [throws Throwable] from your method declaration.